# Drawing points on Argand plane

Tags: complex-numbers

> The points $5 + 5i$, $1− 3i$, $− 4 + 2i$ and $−2 + 6i$ in the
>   Argand plane are:
>
> (a) Collinear
>
> (b) Concyclic
>
> (c) The vertices of a parallelogram
>
> (d) The vertices of a square

So when I drew the diagram, I got an rectangle in the 1st and 2nd quadrant. So, are they vertices of parallelogram? I am not sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a rectangle, and it's certainly not contained only in the first and second quadrants.

Try plotting the points again.

*If* you make further efforts on your own and need help, mouse over this box.

> [image]
>
> ```
> Show[ListPlot[{{5, 5}, {1, -3}, {-4, 2}, {-2, 6}},
> PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}}, AspectRatio -> 1,
> PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[12]],
> Graphics[Text[Style["5+5[ImaginaryI]", Directive[18]], {5, 4.1}]],
> Graphics[Text[Style["1-3[ImaginaryI]", Directive[18]], {2.2, -3}]],
> Graphics[Text[Style["-4+2[ImaginaryI]", Directive[18]], {-4, 2.7}]],
> Graphics[Text[Style["-2+6[ImaginaryI]", Directive[18]], {-3.4, 6}]]]
> ```

Comment: parallelogram ??

Comment: Do you see that the points do not form a rectangle?

Comment: well..may be not..they do? :O

Comment: I dont see a rec. gosh! am so poor?

Answer (score 1):

Its not collinear, nor a square, nor a parallelogram. Therefore, it must be Concyclic